# WebRTC: Selection from audio input devices

Tags: javascript, input, webrtc, selection, device

This is used for selection audio output by setting sink ID to deviceId.

```
$('#outputAudio')[0].setSinkId(device_id);
```

Is it possible to select an audio input device (microphone) in a similar way?

Comment: You should accept the answer, not put the answer in your question, unless you're asking something else. If you're asking something else, it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know that this option is possible by setting deviceId to getUserMedia audio constraints. It looks something like that:

```
constraints: {
 "audio": {
  "deviceId": "xkcTfaf1uUJ/q1po904WtoZqV1P/rsUjp889EOO0j6Q="
 },
 "video": false
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  // do something
}).catch(function(err) {
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call getUserMedia with a device id. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ shows the canonical sample for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The canonical sample does not work for me if a video source is not allowed. So it looks like it is somehow attaching audio input to video element. I would like to select audio input and set it to different audio output without using video source. Is something like that possible?